# How to get all changed file names, across all commits to a branch using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'm using a simple GitHub Action to try to return all changed files.

Within the first commit to my branch, I have added a new directory with multiple files within in.  I've then been creating sequential commits to the same branch to update my GH Action Workflow.

When I try to get a list of the changed files, my only change is always the GH Action workflow file, the added files within the new directory are never returned.

My structure is:

```
.github/
   workflows/
     myworkflow.yml
new-directory/
   files/ 
     addedfile1
     addedfile2
```

My GitHub Action looks like this:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
            fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Get Changed Directories
        id: changed-directories
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35
        with:
            fetch_depth: 0

      - name: List all changed files
        run: |
          for file in ${{ steps.changed-directories.outputs.all_changed_and_modified_files }}; do
            echo $file
          done
```

(This utilizes this marketplace Action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/changed-files)

The result is:

```
.github/workflows/myworkflow.yml
```

However, doesn't show the added files within the new directory.  I added this in the first commit to my branch, and I wonder if that is where the issue lies - I've tried updating the fetch-depth, but so far, this hasn't helped.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You might have better luck just utilizing the GitHub CLI with the GitHub API to get the files changed in the PR. `run: gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/PULL_NUMBER/files`. See: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api and https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-pull-requests-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't posted the whole workflow but it seems to me that it runs on `push` event, in which case there is one problem: **the action doesn't know what is the base to compare your branch with**. You can test it by setting `base_sha` to some arbitrary commit's SHA:

```yaml
- name: Get Changed Directories
  id: changed-directories
  uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35
  with:
      base_sha: YOUR_SHA
```

I checked the action's GitHub issues and even though the issue has been reported, there was no clear example how it's supposed to work on push. I think you have two options:

**1. Stick to running the workflow on a `pull_request` event.** This way the action would know what to compare your branch with.

**2. Use additional trickery to set `base_sha` to the one of your chosen branch** (in this example *origin/master*):

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
        fetch-depth: 0

  - name: Base SHA
    id: base-sha
    run: echo "sha=$(git rev-parse origin/master)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  
  - name: Get Changed Directories
    id: changed-directories
    uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v35
    with:
        base_sha: "${{ steps.base-sha.outputs.sha }}"
  
  - name: List all changed files
    run: |
      for file in ${{ steps.changed-directories.outputs.all_changed_and_modified_files }}; do
        echo $file
      done
```